# Help fix typos in Stack Overflow Jobs

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

What should I do if I saw typo or some error info in jobs?

How can I help people to fix if? What is the best way to say people from company about this errors?

Comment: Honestly I'd ignore it and move on. It's the company's job to proof-read their adverts before submitting them.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly It's marketing James, you'll be triggered and send them a message, this way they'll have a way of replying and bring you in smoothly.

Comment: The typical process is to apply to the job, work your way over into the HR department, and then fix the typo. Patience is a virtue, they say.

Comment: Actually right now i have no button "Ask a question" or this button is hidden somewhere.
Maybe i have no enough rating. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @nick_gabpe - some companies allow you to "ask a question" others dont.  As strange as that sounds.  The thing is some companies on SO fully use the jobs platform to allow candidates to submit for a job directly throguh SO.  Others use SO simply to advertise a job but then take you to yet another system to actually apply for a job (such as ADP, etc).